# Not get path type:array form DB in response

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

On  fetching the schema of post we can't get the path of type:array in response. but the path is show in DB.

my post fetching code

```
const post_modal = require("../../modals/post_model/postModel");

exports.fetchpost_control = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const response = await post_modal.find().populate("comment").exec();

    res.json({response});

  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send({
      success: false,
      data: e.message,
      message: "Internal server error"
    });
  }
};
```

Status of my DB

[image: status of DB]

what i get in response of fetchpost, in response i have

## not getting the arrays of  comment and like

[image: what i get in response of fetchpost, in response i have not getting the arrays of comment and like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mongoose schema make sure that that your `comment` key in your `posts_fos` documents have have a reference to the comments collections. Something like:

```
comments: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'comments_fos'
        }]
```

Then your db query works like:

```
const response = await post_modal.find().populate("comment").lean();
```

Or if you are using models you pass the model in like so:

```
const response = await post_modal.find().populate({ path: 'comment', model: commentModel }).lean();
```

Further explanation on using populate can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-populate-method/).